# Cannot @Autowire dependencies in custom Spring validators

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm trying to validate my Hibernate entities using custom constraints and validators, and some of these validators have dependencies on other services like a configuration class. I understand Spring provides a specific `SpringConstraintValidatorFactory` precisely for this purpose, and being new at Spring, I found some code to declare the corresponding bean:

**The custom validator**

```
@Service
public class MyCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, Integer> {

    @Autowire
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyConstraint constraint) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer someValueToValidate, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { 
        // doStuff 
    }
```

**MyService class**

```
@Service("MyService")
public class MyService {

    private Configuration configuration;

    @PostConstruct
    private void map() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/my_config.yml");
        configuration = objectMapper.readValue(stream, Configuration.class);
    }

    private static class Configuration {
        // some getters and setters
    }
}
```

**Application class**

```
    @Bean
    Validator validator(AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure()
            .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
            .buildValidatorFactory();

        return validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }
```

Even with this solution, I get a NPE on `myService` when calling the validator on my entity.

Comment: How does `MyService` look like ? And where are you using it ? there is nothing in the example

Comment: @john, I updated the description. MyService is just a class that abstracts a YML configuration file.

Comment: Can you share with us main config file (xml or java class)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses own validator so you should override it and use spring validator in hibernate properties using HibernatePropertiesCustomizer.

Here you can find more details: [Spring Boot - Hibernate custom constraint doesn't inject Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212117/spring-boot-hibernate-custom-constraint-doesnt-inject-service)