# Spring Boot - Hibernate custom constraint doesn't inject Service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I will try to ignore other details and make it short:

```
@Entity
public class User
    @UniqueEmail
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
}

@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidatior implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail,String>, InitializingBean {

    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueEmail constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(userService == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        if(value == null) return false;
        return !userService.isEmailExisted(value);
    }

}
```

This will work when the validation is made in Spring (Spring MVC `@Valid` or  inject the `Validator` using `@Autowire`), everything will be fine. 
But as soon as I save the entity using Spring Data JPA:

```
User save = userRepository.save(newUser);
```

Hibernate will try to instantiate a new `UniqueEmailValidatior` without inject the `UserService` bean.
So how can I make Hibernate to use my `UniqueEmailValidatior` component without it instantiate a new one.
I could disable hibernate validation using `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` but I hope there is another way

Update: Here is my UserService:

```
   @Autowired private Validator validator;
   @Transactional
    public SimpleUserDTO newUser(UserRegisterDTO user) {
        validator.validate(user);
        System.out.println("This passes");
        User newUser = new User(user.getUsername(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()),user.getEmail(),
                "USER",
                user.getAvatar());
        User save = userRepository.save(newUser);
        System.out.println("This won't pass");
        return ....
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing things to override/configure the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`? Hibernate should use the same as Spring and as such auto wiring should work. Or do you configure things explicitly for Spring Data JPA?

Comment: I don't override anything in my Configuration, you can check the updated part too

Comment: I don't see configuration in your update (only a service)?

Comment: I let Spring Boot autoconfigure everything database related so I don't have any configuration

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would expect that Spring Boot would wire the existing validator to the `EntityManager` apparently it doesn't.

You can use a `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` and add properties to the existing `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` and register the `Validator`.

**NOTE:** I'm assuming here that you are using Spring Boot 2.0

```
@Component
public class ValidatorAddingCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final ObjectProvider<javax.validation.Validator> provider;

    public ValidatorAddingCustomizer(ObjectProvider<javax.validation.Validator> provider) {
        this.provider=provider;
    }

    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        Validator validator = provider.getIfUnique();
        if (validator != null) {
            hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this should wire the existing validator with hibernate and with that it will make use of auto wiring.

**NOTE:** You don't need to use `@Component` on the validator the autowiring is build into the validator factory before returning the instance of the `Validator`.

Comment: I've added ValidatorAddingCustomizer but it still not work, I've updated the sample project in case you're interested

Comment: You can try debugging and see if this is getting called (you have put it in a package that is available for component scanning?). I did a `getIfUnique` could be that there isn't a unique one (but multiple). You can try the `getObject` instead and see if that works or fails.

Comment: It get called, the validator is LocalValidatorFactoryBean, but somehow the UserService still not get injected

Comment: Any chance someone familiar with the Spring ecosystem could open an issue for Spring/Spring Data? As mentioned in my answer below, it's the second time in a row we have this issue. It would be nice if it could get fixed once and for all.

Comment: Anyone can register a Github issue... I would start with Spring Boot to have it included in there (or at least that it was made possible).

Comment: While searching for this issue, I have come across a Spring Issue that is probably this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15829. It might be useful to track progress there.

Answer (score 1):

To have the Spring beans injected into your `ConstraintValidator`, you need a specific `ConstraintValidatorFactory` which should be passed at the initialization of the `ValidatorFactory`.

Something along the lines of:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
    .configure()
    .constraintValidatorFactory( new MySpringAwareConstraintValidatorFactory( mySpringContext ) )
    .build();
```

with `MySpringAwareConstraintValidatorFactory` being a `ConstraintValidatorFactory` that injects the beans inside your `ConstraintValidator`.

I suspect the `ValidatorFactory` used by Spring Data does not inject the validators when creating them, which is unfortunate.

I suppose you should be able to override it. Or better, you should open an issue against Spring Boot/Spring Data so that they properly inject the `ConstraintValidator`s as it the second time in a row we have this question on SO.

Comment: Spring already does that with the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and more, the auto wiring part. You don't need a special `ConstraintValidatorFactory`. You need to make JPA aware of the correct validator.

Comment: This is true for the `ValidatorFactory` used by Spring MVC (and indeed it works in the OP's case). What I'm wondering is if this is the `ValidatorFactory` passed to Hibernate ORM for the JPA validation.

Comment: Not by default (although I expected Spring Boot to do so). However letting Hibernate (or JPA for that matter) use it isn't very hard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite big to post here. Please check for this article in S.O to help you with. This should help you get started.

[Test Custom Validator with Autowired spring Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610061/test-custom-validator-with-autowired-spring-service)

The problem is hibernate will no way know spring definition. However you can make Entities to be aware of any type of `javax.validation` types. Hope this helps.